# Why this deserialized throws me StackOverflow exception?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, ixmlserializable

When I try to deserialized my FooContainer (List) throws me an error. Please, just watch the last part of this code.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    object Value { get; }
}

public abstract class Foo<T> : IFoo
{
    [XmlElement("Value")]
    public T Value { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    object IFoo.Value { get { return Value; } }
}

public class FooA : Foo<string> { }
public class FooB : Foo<int> { }
public class FooC : Foo<List<Double>> { }

[XmlRoot("Foos")]
public class FooContainer : List<IFoo>, IXmlSerializable
{
    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FooContainer));
        serial.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        ForEach(x =>
            {
                XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(x.GetType(),
            new Type[] { typeof(FooA), typeof(FooB), typeof(FooC) });
                serial.Serialize(writer, x);
            });
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FooContainer fooList = new FooContainer()
        {
            new FooA() { Value = "String" },
            new FooB() { Value = 2 },
            new FooC() { Value = new List<double>() {2, 3.4 } } 
        };

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(fooList.GetType(),
            new Type[] { typeof(FooA), typeof(FooB), typeof(FooC) });
        System.IO.TextWriter textWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\movie.xml");
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, fooList);
        textWriter.Close();

        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\temp\movie.xml");
        var a = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to understand what `IXmlSerializable` is for. It's meant for *overriding* the default behaviour of an `XmlSerializer`. If you just spin up another `XmlSerializer` to actually serialize/deserialize in your `WriteXml`/`ReadXml` methods then yes, you will get a `StackOverflowException` because that serializer is going to call the exact same `WriteXml`/`ReadXml`/ method it came from on exactly the same object.

Just get rid of that `IXmlSerializable` implementation, since it doesn't actually do anything. Or read this CP article:

[How to Implement IXmlSerializable Correctly](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly)

Basically, you are supposed to use the standard `Read*` and `Write*` methods on `XmlReader` or `XmlWriter` to read or write the object.

It's not necessarily *always* wrong to use an `XmlSerializer` inside a `ReadXml` or `WriteXml` method - as long as you're using it to serialize/deserialize a *different* object, one which neither equals nor contains an instance of the declaring type in the object graph.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got what I should do now. My doubt until now is how can I store the property Value if is T dataType? XmlSerialization write each type of datatype, I really have no idea about how to write this value using XmlWriter.

Comment: @DarfZon: Generics and XML don't mix particularly well. In your specific yet abstract example, the only way you could be sure that `Foo<T>` is actually serializable is to place a constraint on `T` which you know is serializable. Right now it doesn't look like `Foo<T>` even does much of anything; maybe if you explained more about what your real problem is (in a new question) some people might be able to help get you straightened out.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same Problem:

To me it seems that you are missing `set` in your interface `IFoo` or class `Foo`. Without `set` the object becomes readonly and you will receive a `StackOverflowException` when trying to deserialize XML to Object.

I simply added `set` to my attributes, and the thing solved itself.

Comment: Right: The deserializer uses the setter as well. Make sure you have a public constructor (without Parameters) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd debug it to make sure, but my guess is your implementation of `ReadXml` is recursive.  `ReadXml` calls `Deserialize`, which calls `ReadXml`, which calls `Deserialize`, etc.

`ReadXml` should read the xml using the reader that's passed in and hydrate the object (i.e. `this`) based on the Xml data.

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.readxml.aspx)

> The ReadXml method must reconstitute your object using the information
>   that was written by the WriteXml method.
>
> When this method is called, the reader is positioned at the start of
>   the element that wraps the information for your type. That is, just
>   before the start tag that indicates the beginning of a serialized
>   object. When this method returns, it must have read the entire element
>   from beginning to end, including all of its contents. Unlike the
>   WriteXml method, the framework does not handle the wrapper element
>   automatically. Your implementation must do so. Failing to observe
>   these positioning rules may cause code to generate unexpected runtime
>   exceptions or corrupt data.
>
> When implementing this method, you should consider the possibility
>   that a malicious user might provide a well-formed but invalid XML
>   representation in order to disable or otherwise alter the behavior of
>   your application.